# ORA-06550 line 10, column 41: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, sys-refcursor, bind-variables

I am executing an anonymous PL/SQL block from C# but I am getting an error like below:

> ORA-06550 line 10, column 41: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ","
>   when expecting one of the following:

My code:

```
OracleDB AppConn = new OracleDB();
OracleDataReader eligiblereader = null;

 string id = "2304502001101";
 long provider = 667;
 long policy = 150;
 DateTime to = Convert.ToDateTime("2015/05/06");
using (OracleConnection con = AppConn.Connection)
{
 OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

 cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = @"declare 
                  p_id   VARCHAR2;
                  p_policy_id   NUMBER;
                  p_provider_id   NUMBER;
                  p_date        DATE;
                  p_tob         tob_type;
                 begin
                                 pbm_pkg.get_member_tob(p_id,p_policy_id,p_provider_id,p_date,p_tob);
open :refcur for select tob_type.benefit_id from dual;
end;";
OracleParameter p = cmd.Parameters.Add(
                         "rs", OracleDbType.RefCursor,
                         DBNull.Value,
                         ParameterDirection.Output);
 OracleParameter p_id = new OracleParameter();
  p_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
  p_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  p_id.Value = id;

OracleParameter p_policy_id = new OracleParameter();
p_policy_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
p_policy_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
p_policy_id.Value = policy;

OracleParameter p_provider_id = new OracleParameter();
p_provider_id.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Int64;
p_provider_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
p_provider_id.Value = provider;

OracleParameter p_date = new OracleParameter();
p_date.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date;
p_date.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
p_date.Value = to;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_id);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_policy_id);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_provider_id);
cmd.Parameters.Add(p_date);

    try
    {
    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

eligiblereader = ((OracleRefCursor)cmd.Parameters[4].Value).GetDataReader();

 while (eligiblereader.Read())
 {
  string id = eligiblereader.GetValue(0).ToString();

}
}
catch (Exception ex)
 {
}
finally
 {
con.Close();
}
return View();
        }
```

The error is coming when the command is executing 'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();'

I think I am missing something in anonymous block.

Comment: I removed  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; now I am getting ora-01006 bind variable does not exist

Comment: @downvoters can u pls say whats he problem in this question?

Comment: I think whoever the downvoter is, doesn't care to leave a comment. Too coward to do it anonymously. Anyway, please look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> p_id   VARCHAR2;

This is certainly incorrect syntax and will throw a compilation error.

**Error reproduce:**

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    p_id VARCHAR2;
  3  BEGIN
  4    NULL;
  5  END;
  6  /
  p_id VARCHAR2;
       *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 8:
PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)


SQL>
```

So, you must specify the **string length constraint between 1 .. 32767**.

**Solution:**

Specify the required length for the string variable.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    p_id VARCHAR2(20);
  3  BEGIN
  4    NULL;
  5  END;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

> open :refcur for select tob_type.benefit_id from dual;

You need to declare the bind variable for the **refcursor**.

For example,

```
SQL> var r refcursor
SQL>
SQL> BEGIN
  2    OPEN :r FOR SELECT empno,ename FROM emp;
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print r

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER
      7876 ADAMS
      7900 JAMES
      7902 FORD
      7934 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Lalit but now im receiving ora-01006 bind variable does not exist

Comment: @Sachu Please see my update. Not sure why the downvote by someone?

Comment: yup this solved that error. but cluless how declare  p_tob         tob_type; this is the out parameter from oracle procedure having the type of a table object..

Comment: @Sachu I I understand correctly, `p_tob` is the OUT parameter and you want to use it later in the anonymous block. What is the data type of it?

Comment: @ Lalit.. it's a table structure object created by our db admin.  Now I asked him to make the out parameter as reference cursor so i can avoid this method.

Comment: An object type is better than a weakly typed cursor. So, test it before moving to production. All the best!

Comment: Yup..object is better than cursor..but i'm not able to fetch that object data in c# :( that's why i asked him to make cursor..

Comment: I am not a front-end C# developer, but I guess you need to read the dataobject and display on a data window. Probably, you could search google on how to do that. As a workaround  if the cursor helps you then well and good.